# Connecting to Bluetooth Thermal Printer using iPhone

Tags: ios4, bluetooth, thermal-printer

Is there or is there not a way to connect my iPhone (sdk 4.0 and above) to a bluetooth printer (Looking for connecting a Thermal Printer for printing a receipt) to execute some printing tasks? I'm developing the app, so what framework could possibly do this? I see that Apple's External Accessory Framework handles bluetooth communication, but is it possible to print using that framework? Is there any Thermal Printer supported with AirPrint. I did not find any.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

there are Wifi printers available. We can use one of them. Please see this [link](http://www.starmicronics.com/Printer/PrinterDesc.aspx?PageId=14&PrinterId=105).

Comment: did you manage to find a way to print to receipt printers by Wifi or bluetooth?

Comment: Do you know something more about that please?